# GeekTrust: Traffic problem - functional programming

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming

First attempt to write functional programming, been following OO paradigm all through my programming journey

Please review the code and let me know if any comments and violations of functional programming?

King Shan wants to visit the suburb of **A** and has 2 possible orbits and 3 possible vehicles to choose from.
Your coding challenge is to determine which orbit and vehicle King Shan should take to reach **A** the fastest

#### Rules:

- **Orbits** have distance, craters, traffic speed, A vehicle cannot travel faster than the traffic speed for an orbit.

  (for example) *So even though a car’s max speed is 20 megamiles/
  hour, it can only go at 10 megamiles/hour if that is the traffic speed for that orbit.*
- **Vehicles** have speed in megamiles/hour, minutes to travel in a single craters
- **Weather** conditions (affects the number of craters in an orbit):

  There are three types of weathers

  1. Sunny - craters reduce by 10%. Car, bike, and tuk-tuk can be used in
     this weather.
  2. Rainy - craters increase by 20%. Car and tuk-tuk can
     be used in this weather.
  3. Windy - no change to the number of craters.
     Car and bike can be used in this weather.
- if there is a **tie** in which vehicle to
  choose, use bike, tuk-tuk, car in that order.

##### Vehicle Options:

1. **BIKE** - 10 megamiles/hour, time taken in craters 2 minutes, travel in Sunny/Windy
2. **TUKTUK** - 12 megamiles/hour, time taken in craters 1 minute, travel in Sunny/Rainy
3. **CAR** - 20 megamiles/hour, time taken in craters 3 minutes, travel in Sunny/Windy/Rainy

##### Orbit options:

- **Orbit 1** - 18 mega miles & 20 craters to cross
- **Orbit 2** - 20 mega
  miles & 10 craters to cross

**Sample I/O**

> Input: Weather is Sunny 
> Input: Orbit1 traffic speed is 12 megamiles/hour 
> Input: Orbit2 traffic speed is 10 megamiles/hour 
> Expected Output: Vehicle TukTuk on Orbit1

#### Solution

**Data**

```
const weathers = {
    SUNNY: {
      craterImpactingPercentage: -10
    },
    RAINY: {
      craterImpactingPercentage: 20
    },
    WINDY: {
      craterImpactingPercentage: 0
    }
  };
  
  const vehicles = [{
      name: 'TukTuk',
      ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.RAINY],
      speedInMmph: 12,
      minsTakenInCrater: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Bike',
      ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.WINDY],
      speedInMmph: 10,
      minsTakenInCrater: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'Car',
      ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.RAINY, weathers.WINDY],
      speedInMmph: 20,
      minsTakenInCrater: 3
    }
  ];
  
  let orbits = [{
    name: 'Orbit1',
    distanceInMm: 18,
    trafficSpeed: 12,
    craters: 20
  }, {
    name: 'Orbit2',
    distanceInMm: 20,
    trafficSpeed: 10,
    craters: 10
  }];
```

`getRidableVehicles` filters the ridable vehicle for the given weather

```
const getRidableVehicles = (vehicles, weather) => {
      return vehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.ridableWeathers.includes(weather));
};
```

`getTravelTime` calculates the travel time for the given `vehicle` on given `orbit` with craters in it

```
const MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60;
const getTravelTime = (vehicle, orbit, noOfCraters) => {
      return (orbit.trafficSpeed < vehicle.speedInMmph ? (orbit.distanceInMm / orbit.trafficSpeed) : (orbit.distanceInMm / vehicle.speedInMmph)) * MINUTES_IN_HOUR + noOfCraters * vehicle.minsTakenInCrater;
};
```

`getNoOfCraters` calculates the number of craters from the `orbit` for the given `weather`

```
const PERCENTAGE = 100;
const getNoOfCraters = (orbit, weather) => {
       return parseInt(orbit.craters + (orbit.craters * weather.craterImpactingPercentage / PERCENTAGE));
  }
```

`getFastestJourney` calls `getRidableVehicles` and gets ridable vehicles then calculates the travelTime on each `orbit` and reduces to the shortest travel time `journey`, in case of `tie` considers minimum speed vehicle among tied `journey`

```
   const getFastestJourney = (vehicles, orbits, weather) => {
    return getRidableVehicles(vehicles, weather)
      .flatMap(vehicle =>
        orbits.map(orbit => ({
          vehicle: vehicle.name,
          orbit: orbit.name,
          travelTime: getTravelTime(vehicle, orbit, getNoOfCraters(orbit, weather)),
          vehicleSpeed: vehicle.speedInMmph,
        })))
      .reduce((journey, otherJourney) => reduceToFastestJourney(journey, otherJourney));
  };
  
  const reduceToFastestJourney = (journey, otherJourney) => {
    return journey.travelTime === otherJourney.travelTime && journey.vehicleSpeed < otherJourney.vehicleSpeed || journey.travelTime < otherJourney.travelTime ? journey : otherJourney;
  }
```

```js
function initialLoad() {
  console.log( getTravelPlan(vehicles, orbits, weathers.SUNNY))
  document.getElementById("outcome").innerHTML =
    getTravelPlan(vehicles, orbits, weathers.SUNNY);
}


const weathers = {
  SUNNY: {
    craterImpactingPercentage: -10
  },
  RAINY: {
    craterImpactingPercentage: 20
  },
  WINDY: {
    craterImpactingPercentage: 0
  }
};

const vehicles = [{
    name: 'TukTuk',
    ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.RAINY],
    speedInMmph: 12,
    minsTakenInCrater: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Bike',
    ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.WINDY],
    speedInMmph: 10,
    minsTakenInCrater: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Car',
    ridableWeathers: [weathers.SUNNY, weathers.RAINY, weathers.WINDY],
    speedInMmph: 20,
    minsTakenInCrater: 3
  }
];

let orbits = [{
  name: 'Orbit1',
  distanceInMm: 18,
  trafficSpeed: 12,
  craters: 20
}, {
  name: 'Orbit2',
  distanceInMm: 20,
  trafficSpeed: 10,
  craters: 10
}];


const MINUTES_IN_HOUR = 60,
  PERCENTAGE = 100;

const getRidableVehicles = (vehicles, weather) => {
  return vehicles.filter(vehicle => vehicle.ridableWeathers.includes(weather));
};

const getTravelTime = (vehicle, orbit, noOfCraters) => {
  return (orbit.trafficSpeed < vehicle.speedInMmph ? (orbit.distanceInMm / orbit.trafficSpeed) : (orbit.distanceInMm / vehicle.speedInMmph)) * MINUTES_IN_HOUR + noOfCraters * vehicle.minsTakenInCrater;
};


const getNoOfCraters = (orbit, weather) => {
  return parseInt(orbit.craters + (orbit.craters * weather.craterImpactingPercentage / PERCENTAGE));
}

const getFastestJourney = (vehicles, orbits, weather) => {
  return getRidableVehicles(vehicles, weather)
    .flatMap(vehicle =>
      orbits.map(orbit => ({
        vehicle: vehicle.name,
        orbit: orbit.name,
        travelTime: getTravelTime(vehicle, orbit, getNoOfCraters(orbit, weather)),
        vehicleSpeed: vehicle.speedInMmph,
      })))
    .reduce((journey, otherJourney) => reduceToFastestJourney(journey, otherJourney));
};

const reduceToFastestJourney = (journey, otherJourney) => {
  return journey.travelTime === otherJourney.travelTime && journey.vehicleSpeed < otherJourney.vehicleSpeed || journey.travelTime < otherJourney.travelTime ? journey : otherJourney;
}

const getTravelPlan = (vehicles, orbits, weather) => {
  console.log("Input: Weather is SUNNY");
  orbits.forEach(orbit => console.log(`${orbit.name} traffic speed is ${orbit.trafficSpeed}`));

  return parseOutcome(getFastestJourney(vehicles, orbits, weather));
}

const parseOutcome = (outcome) => `Expected Output: Vehicle ${outcome.vehicle} on ${outcome.orbit}`;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY id="outcome" onload=initialLoad()>
        <h1>
    TEST
    </h1>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```